# Position Discord widget in certain spot on webpage

Tags: html, css

I have the premade widget, and I am trying to position it on lower right hand corner with a fixed position so it stays there regardless of scrolling. I for the love of me cannot get it to go where I want it to, it just stays under the content. Please help.

```html
<iframe src="https://discord.com/widget?id=769639393924481044&theme=dark" width="350" height="500" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe>
```

I have tried using a div as done on w3 schools, again unable to make it work.

```html
<div.fixed><iframe src="https://discord.com/widget?id=769639393924481044&theme=dark" width="350" height="500" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" sandbox="allow-popups allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe></div.fixed>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<div.fixed>` does not exist. You have to add a `class`. The name of the class can be what ever you like. In CSS you will then need the `.` to access the class. Something like this will work

```css
.fix-me {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    background-color: orange;
    
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="fix-me">
  <div>what ever content</div>
</div>
```